# Помогите с условиями и циклами на Си

Tags: c, циклы, ввод, условия

Делал прогу, в которой нужно создать два массива-матрицы n на n с динамической памятью. С этим все ок. После этого нужно было сделать функцию, которая определяет +, - или * и сделать соответствующие вычисления для матриц. После задания условия - все ок, но после начала цикла for код отказывается работать. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double** new_matrix(int n){
    int i;
    double** matrix = calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
         matrix[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    }
    return matrix;
}

void input(int n, double **mat){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(j =0; j<n; j++){
            printf("input matrix[%d][%d]", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void print_mat(int n, double **mat){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(j =0; j<n; j++){
            printf("%lf\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
double** calculat_mat(int n, double **mat1, double **mat2){
    double **res = new_matrix(n);
    char c;
    printf("+, -, or *? \n");
    scanf("%s", &c);

    if (c == '+'){
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                res[i][j] = mat1[i][j]+mat2[i][j];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    else if (c == '-'){
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                res[i][j] = mat1[i][j]-mat2[i][j];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    else if (c == '*'){
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                res[i][j] = 0;
                for(int p=0; p<n; p++){
                    res[i][j] += mat1[i][p]*mat2[p][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    else{
        return res;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    char c;

    printf("Write size of matrix: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double **mat1 = new_matrix(n);
    double **mat2 = new_matrix(n);
    double **res = new_matrix(n);

    printf("Input matrix number 1: \n");
    input(n, mat1);

    printf("Input matrix number 2: \n");
    input(n, mat2);


    res = calculat_mat(n, mat1, mat2);
    print_mat(n, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Если код вам кажется кривым - сорян, я только начал учить Си.

Comment: Для начала, если уж `c` - `char`, то не `scanf("%s", &c);`, а `scanf("%c", &c);`

Comment: Не, с проверкой условия вс ок, сам цикл отказывает в работе

Comment: Я насчитал тут 11 `for` — все не работают? Что именно и как не работает?

Comment: В функции calculat_mat после условий if (c =='+') ну и так далее - циклы for не рабэ. Думал, что там условие не работает из-за неправильно типа char, но после проверок оказалось, что с ними все окей, но вот если попробовать что-нибудь вывести внутри цикла - ничего не выйдет.

Comment: Да вот как раз со вводом символа операции у вас и нелады... Сделайте правильно - и все будет работать: https://ideone.com/PeSj6m У вас в буфере ввода висит невоспринятый `\n` после последнего чтения, а читая, как строку, вы именно его и считываете. Кстати, вам стоило добавить одну строку с отладочным выводом, типа `printf("Op: %c\n",c)` после `scanf`, чтобы убедиться в этом. И еще раз - если вы и дальше вопреки стандарту языка будете утверждать, что можно читать `%s` в `char`, то вы очень скоро прибежите сюда с очередным вопросом...

Comment: У меня с  "%с" вообще не дает ввести что либо, просто скипает(

Comment: Пробел в `" %c"` по ссылке видели?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Правда я вот не понял на кой там пробел, но да ладно. Когда нормально выучу си - тогда пойму

Comment: Чтобы пропустить все пробельные символы, в том числе оставшийся в буфере ввода символ перевода строки.

Answer (score 2):

Неверное чтение символа.

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

надо заменить на

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Так, во-первых, будет читаться *символ* (не будет выхода за пределы отведенной памяти), а во-вторых, будут пропускаться все пробельные символы (главное - остающийся после ввода числа символ перевода строки).